# Partially specify type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-parameter

```
  def apply[T, LP <: ViewGroupLayoutParams[_, TSpinner[T]]]()(implicit context: android.content.Context, defaultLayoutParam: TSpinner[T] => LP): TSpinner[T] = {
    val v = new TSpinner[T]
    v.<<.parent.+=(v)
   v
}
```

Is it possible to only give one parameter?

`val v = new TSpinner[T]()`

Because normally, without paramter `T`, other paramters is all implicit + inferred

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this, unless the idea is that it's likely a duplicate. What you're asking for is one of the holy grails of Scala—it's not possible as stated, but in some cases there are workarounds that aren't too awful.

Answer (score 0):

You could define LP as an abstract type member, removing LP from the function's type list.

```
type LP[T,O] <: ViewGroupLayoutParams[O, TSpinner[T]]

def apply[T]]()(implicit context: android.content.Context, defaultLayoutParam: TSpinner[T] => LP[T,_]): TSpinner[T]
```